# Rendering HTML-Content in Atom Feed with Rails atom_feed helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed, atom-feed

I've got some problems with the (fairly undocumented) atom_feed helper.

I'ld love to do something like this:

```
for blogpost in @blogposts
  feed.entry(blogpost) do |entry|
    entry.title(blogpost.title)
    entry.content(render :partial => '...', :object => blogpost), :type => 'html')
  end
end
```

But that doesn't seem to work and I have no Idea how to render HTML instead of some inline text!

Let's make an example:

```
entry.content (<div style=" ... "> + article.body + </div> + <div style=" ... "> + <img src=" + article.img.url + ..... )
```

Writing and styling up the content directly in the index.atom.builder is really annoying.

Isn't there a way to render a html-partial in that context?

Could somebody help me.

Thanks allot
PascalTurbo

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently and put my findings into a post, see here: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/14

A fairly simple version would be like this, there is more in the link:

app/views/articles/index.atom.builder

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "Title"
  feed.updated @articles.first.created_at

  @articles.each do |article|
    feed.entry article do |entry|
      entry.title article.titl
      entry.content article.body, :type => 'html'

      entry.author do |author|
        author.name article.author
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but that's not what I've meant.

In this way, "body" must contain all necessary content. But for rich-HTML content it would be necessary to render a partial with the content.

I've added an example to above post.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Just a wild guess as I can't try at the moment - how about `entry.content :type => "text/html" do render .... end` ?

Comment: This results in this message:

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial /galleries/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:atom], :locale=>[:de, :de]}

Obviously it tries to render some atom-content instead of html-content.

Comment: What happens if you try to force it like this: `render :partial => '/path/name.html.erb', :locals =>{:var => ... }`

Comment: An addition: there is a render_to_string method in Rails that could be useful, however this one is marked as deprecated and I am not aware of a replacement.

Comment: forcing the locals is ignored :-/

Comment: This is the code:

entry.content( render :partial => '/blogposts/_content.html.erb', :locals => {:formats => [:html]}, :type => 'html' )


and this the error message: 
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial /blogposts/_content.html with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:atom], :locale=>[:de, :de]} in view paths "/Users/pascalturbo/Dropbox/Development/Webdesign/rails/homepage/app/views", "/Users/pascalturbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/kaminari-0.10.4/app/views", "/Users/pascalturbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/devise-1.1.8/app/views"):

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an old bug. Best solution I found is to make a duplicate of the partial with the .atom.erb extentions. E.g.

_inner_slider.html.erb became _inner_slider.atom.erb

This is because Rails is looking for a certain format.

This solution is not DRY at all and other alternatives are more than welcome.